# Rails migration file not being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I ran a `rails g migration rename_user_id_columns` and it says:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140617192830_rename_user_id_columns.rb
```

The problem is this file does not actually exist in the folder, and also I ran a search on my whole computer and couldn't find it. Interestingly, when I try to then create the file manually in Sublime and save, it tells me I'm going to be overwriting an existing file. Whenever I try to run the manual migration, I get the following error.

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RenameUserIdColumns
```

Comment: Sublime???? Ok, are you familiar with the option "Project/Refresh Folders"? Running it if files are not displayed usually helps to see the new files. Especially if you are using a mounted volume or a volume of another user.

Comment: hmm i didn't try that, i just refreshed, but will do next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart of the computer fixed this problem for me. But I think going to Project > Refresh Sublime could do the trick as well.